# In TextBox showing float propertie value

Tags: c#, wpf

So i have a float variable in the Application Settings `Properties.Settings.Default.flvalue`, now i want to show this in a TextBox and also edit and save afterwards.

To Show it i have to convert it `toString()` but then i want to Format it like: `1.23`
unfortunately this is not working. Is there any NumberBox in C# WPF or better way to bind the settings variable into a TextBox?

```
       _flvalue.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.flvalue.ToString();

        <TextBox x:Name="_flvalue" Text="{StringFormat={}{0:#,0.0}}""></TextBox>
```

Comment: Format to number `.ToString("N2")` and remove the `Text="{StringFormat={}{0:#,0.0}}"` in xaml.

Comment: "*better way to bind*" - right now you are not binding anything. A WPF data binding would require a public property of the object in the current DataContext. Then you would write `Text="{Binding Path=YourProperty, StringFormat={}{0:#,0.0}}"`, and not assign the Text property in code behind. See [Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0). What you have right now, i.e. `Text="{StringFormat={}{0:#,0.0}}"` is pointless.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work at the moment is that numeric formats only apply to numbers. You're setting text to a string so it's not a number. If you cast or convert to a double instead of ToString() then what you have would kind of work. But you should actually bind a double property from a viewmodel.

Comment: i have to set it to string, the textbox doesn't accept float.